# Selecting number in column “x” randomly between n , m

Tags: excel-formula

I have numbers in a column (i.e., 1 to 10 in column A) and a few numbers in another column (i.e six number in column E). I want to place numbers of column E in column B randomly, so that absolute difference between Ai and Bi is between n and m that place in D1 and D2. I use of AGGREGATE Function

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$2:$E$7/(And(ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)>=$D$1;ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)<=$D$2)),RANDBETWEEN(1,SUMPRODUCT(--(And(ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)>=$D$1;ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)<=$D$2))))
```

But don,t run

Comment: Your question is unclear: Could you provide sample data? You refer in one place to **Column E**, then later to **Column D**.

Comment: You seem to be using both `,` and `;` as separators between arguments - which of those you should use depend on your Language settings, but will never be a mixture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AND` function will flatten your Array to a single item:  `=AND({1,2,4,8}>2,{1,2,3,4}<7)` will become `=AND({False,False,True,True},{True,True,True,False})`, but the next step is `=FALSE`

You want to use `--` and `*` instead, like so: `=--(({1,2,4,8}>2)*--({1,2,3,4}<7)` becomes `=({False,False,True,True})*--({True,True,True,False})` then `={0,0,1,1}*{1,1,1,0}`, and finally `={0,0,1,0}`

Also: Rather than a `SUMPRODUCT` in the middle, would it be simpler/faster to just use a pair of `COUNTIFS`?

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$2:$E$7/--((ABS($E$2:$E$7-$A2)>=$D$1)*(ABS($E$2:$E$7-$A2)<=$D$2)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$7,">=" & ($A2+$D$1),$E$2:$E$7,"<="&($A2+$D$2))+COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$7,">=" & ($A2-$D$2),$E$2:$E$7,"<="&($A2-$D$1))))
```